# Magento 2 URL Rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting, magento2

I tried to do some URL Rewriting on Multi Store Magento 2 (3 languages : fr, en, de) without any success.

What's in place now :
When someone call http://en.mywebsite/my/modulepath => correct action is exectuted.
The 2 following urls (french and german version) also works : fr.mywebsite/my/modulepath, http://de.mywebsite/my/modulepath

What i would like is this : call this specific action from other (3) localized URL paths. In other words trying to have route aliases.

One example : let's say you have one module called "jobs" and you'r trying to show a job details page. 
What i can do now : en.mywebsite/job/id/1 => works and shows correct infos
Also works : fr.mywebsite/job/id/1, de.mywebsite/job/id/1

What i'm trying to do is having these url calling the same action :
- fr.mywebsite/emploi/id/1
- de.mywebsite/beschaftigung/id/1

Any ideas on how i can do that ?

What i tried is :

Setting RewriteCond / RewriteRule rules in .htaccess and even if it does url rewrites, Magento is not able to handle the request since only REQUEST_URI seems to be taken in consideration.
However, it does work with a true 301 Redirect (which i don't want).

Any helps / thoughts about this will be much appreciated.

Note : I roll with apache, mod rewrite enabled on classic LAMP env.